# Handling the sender object in closing event

Tags: wpf, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm getting a bit confused over the sender object in VB .Net. If I have the following event:

```
Private Sub wpfWindow_Closing(sender As Object, e As  
            ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles wpfWindow.Closing

End Sub
```

Then I understand that the sender is the thing which is calling the closing event just before the window closes. However, I am struggling to see how to determine which button was pressed. If I do the following in the event:

```
    Dim aButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    If aButton.Content = "Next" Then
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed Next")
    End If
```

This brings up an error as it can't cast the sender, even though I pressed "Next".

Have also tried:

```
If sender Is btnNext Then
    MessageBox.Show("You pressed Next")
End If
```

But in this case, it just skips it.

At the end of the day, I am just trying to navigate through some WPF windows. There is a starting window which I hide once I move onto the next. The problem is that on the second window I would like to determine if "Next" is pressed rather than "Cancel" or the close button in the top right. If next is pressed, then I would like to close the window and open another one. If the other buttons are pressed, then I would like to close the window and open the starting window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sender` will be the `Window` because `Closing` is the `Windows`'s event.

So you can cast the sender to `Window`, but not to `Button`.

If you have separate `Click` event handlers for your Next and Cancel buttons it shouldn't be difficult to determine which `Button` was clicked. In the `Click` event handler you can do what you originally wanted, casting the `sender` to a `Button` type.

Comment: thanks - knew I had the wrong end of the stick somehow